# What css property is used to remove the gap above and below the meter element?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm trying to remove this whitespace above and below the `meter-bar`, but can't determine what property I need to override from the [User Agent Stylesheet](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css).

[image]

```
/* meter */
meter {
    -webkit-appearance: meter;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    width: 5em;
    vertical-align: -0.2em;
}
meter::-webkit-meter-inner-element {
    -webkit-appearance: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-only !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ddd, #eee 20%, #ccc 45%, #ccc 55%, #ddd);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-only !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ad7, #cea 20%, #7a3 45%, #7a3 55%, #ad7);
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-only !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fe7, #ffc 20%, #db3 45%, #db3 55%, #fe7);
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-only !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f77, #fcc 20%, #d44 45%, #d44 55%, #f77);
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-only !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I tried `padding`, `border`, and `border-box`, but to no avail.

Comment: The height of the `meter` element is 16px, but the `meter-bar` is less than that. So I am trying to make the `meter-bar` fill 100% of the height...but setting it to that height doesn't get rid of the white space.

Comment: vertical-align: top ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif no, did not work